# Cython fast conversion of binary string to int array

Tags: python, arrays, cython, distutils

I have a large binary data file which I want to load into a C array for fast access. The data file just contains a sequence of 4 byte ints.

I get the data via the pkgutil.get_data function, which returns a binary string.
the following code works:

```
import pkgutil
import struct

cdef int data[32487834]

def load_data():
    global data
    py_data = pkgutil.get_data('my_module', 'my_data')
    for i in range(32487834):
        data[i] = <int>struct.unpack('i', py_data[4*i:4*(i+1)])[0]
    return 0

load_data()
```

The problem is that this code is quite slow. Reading the whole data file can take 7 or 8 seconds. Reading the file directly into an array in C only takes 1-2 seconds, but I want to use pkgutil.get_data so that my module can reliably find the data whereever it gets installed.

So, my question is: what's the best way to do this? Is there a way to directly cast the data as an array of ints without all the calls to struct.unpack? And, as a secondary question, is there a way to simply get a pointer to the data to avoid copying 120MB of data unnecessarily?

Alternatively, is there a way to make pkgutil return the file path to the data instead of the data itself (in which case I can use C file IO to read the file quite quickly.

EDIT:

Just for the record, here's the final code used (based on Veedrac's answer):

```
import pkgutil

from cpython cimport array
import array

cdef int[:] data

cdef void load_data():
    global data
    py_data = pkgutil.get_data('my_module', 'my_data')
    data = array.array('i', py_data)

load_data()
```

Everything is quite fast.

Comment: Why not just memory-map it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are you should really just use Numpy:

```
import numpy
import random
import struct

data = struct.pack('i'*100, *[random.randint(0, 1000000) for _ in range(100)])

numpy.fromstring(data, dtype="int32")
#>>> array([642029, 967046, 599565, ...etc], dtype=int32)
```

Then just use any of the [standard methods to get a pointer from that](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/tutorials-NumpyPointerToC).

If you want to avoid Numpy, a faster but less platform-agnostic method would be to go via a char pointer:

```
cdef int *data_view = <int *><char *>data
```

This has lots of "undefined"-ness to it, so be careful. Also be careful not to modify the data!

A good compromize between the two would be to use `cpython.array`:

```
from cpython cimport array
import array

def main(data):
    cdef array.array[int] data_arr = array.array('i', data)
    cdef int *data_ptr = data_arr.data.as_ints
```

which gives you well defined semantics and is fast with built-in libraries.

Comment: Thanks! The second method worked beutifully. I knew there had to be a way to do this efficiently. Am I right in assuming I have to keep a copy of the bytestring in the global scope so it doesn't get garbage collected? As far as platform issues go, is the problem just that some platforms may not use 32 bit ints? Is that actually likely to be a real problem? Or just a theoretical concern?

Comment: For the second case, yes. The others copy (but do so very fast). You can use `numpy.frombuffer` to get a non-copying variant of the first.  // There are a lot of potential problems with the second: it's actually not defined *at all* what the behaviour is. Assuming the compiler and platform make it do something sensible, you still need to worry about endianness and the size of `int`. Luckily it will work most of the time regardless, it's just not required to. There are platforms that do use different endiannesses or different sizes of `int` so it just depends whether you care about them!

Comment: I'm definitely trying to avoid numpy if I can. For access is the cpython array just as fast as a straight c-array? I don't really care if the loading time is slightly longer as long as that's <1s and access is fast.

Comment: Yes, as you end up going through a plain pointer. Access through the `array.array[int]` is slower but still quite fast. Access through a memoryview `int[:]` will be as fast as the pointer version (but also safer). I suggest passing the pointer to C routines and using the memoryview when in Cython.